# Paste is greyed out - ArcGIS 10.4.- Can't edit in ArcMap!

Tags: arcmap, editing, esri-geodatabase

I'm having a silly problem in edit session within ESRI ArcMap 10.4. 
I'm trying to copy from a polygon feature to a polygon feature and when I'm using copy function the paste function turns instantly grey and can't use it. I've tried deselecting the feature, shut-down and restart of the program but with no effect.

The solution is a total restart of the computer but I don't think this is right. 
Is there any other solution or someone who has/had the same problem?

Comment: .lock files? https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009399

Comment: If there's a transient networking error, sometimes the edit session is compromised.

Comment: Are you in Data View or Layout View? This only works in DV.

Comment: I'm in Data View.